# Security risk in making $table public in an eloquent model

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I make all of my eloquent model's `$table` protected because that is what I saw in the tutorial. But now I need to use fluent to create a query, and I wish to access the `$table` via `ModelName::$table` since I don't like hardcoding the name of the table.

So is it safe to make the property of `$table` public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, ye, why not? Even if you leave it as protected, it still can be accessed through Reflection, so there's really no security issue. Or you could access it through the public `getTable` method.